Writing to a file in python does not consistently change its mtime
If I run the following code
import os
import time

def check_different_times():
    try:
        os.remove("temp")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    with open("temp", "w") as f:
        f.write("hi")
    first = os.stat("temp").st_mtime_ns
    time.sleep(0.001)
    with open("temp", "w") as f:
        f.write("b")
    second = os.stat("temp").st_mtime_ns
    return first != second

print(sum(check_different_times() for _ in range(100)))

Based on my understanding of how unix timestamps work, this should print 100, given that 0.001s is 1e6 nanoseconds, so the two modification times should obviously be different.
However, if I run this on my Ubuntu laptop, it prints something like 28 or 30. If I remove the sleep line it prints something like 1 or 2. Is this some weird buffering thing, a bug in Ubuntu, in Python, or a flaw in my understanding of what mtime is?

Some filesystems don't have such precise modification times.

@barmar the filesystem I am using, ext4, certainly has the precision to represent nanosecond timestamps. Setting the timestamp back 1 nanosecond using utime is reflected back on a subsequent stat call.

In python 3.11, time.sleep() was revamped making it more accurate across both windows and Unix. Updating to python 3.11 might fix your issue.

This was on python 3.11
